# Show data from One Model Multiple Table to One Grid in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one Model Class in MVC

```
public  class Employee
    {
        public int empId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public int Age { get; set; }   
        public string Dob { get; set; }       
        public string Email { get; set; }       
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public string Qualification { get; set; }

    }
```

But their data are stored in different tables(3 table in sql server) and I want to show all data in one Web Grid(NOT ON TABLE) using entity framework
.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data is stored in three tables A(a1, a2, a3), B (b1, b2), C (c1, c2) then get the result by joining all 3 tables or based on your business logic which you want to perform and store the result in IEnumerable collection. Finally provide the as data source in Web grid.

You can get data using Entity framework as below

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = (from m in A
                                   join n in B joins m.a1 equals = n.b1 \\join condition
                                   join o in C joins n.b1 equals o.c1 \\put your join condition
                                   select new Employee{
                                   empId=m.a1,
                                   Name = m.a2,
                                   Country = n.b2 //and so on
                                   }).ToList();

   rerurns employees;
```

Now bind employees with web Grid

Answer (score 0):

I used the WebGrid to bind the data from two tables and display in a single page:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {

            string loginUserId = TempData[WebConstants.LoginUserId].ToString();
            string loginUserName = TempData[WebConstants.LoginUserName].ToString();
            string authmode = TempData[WebConstants.AuthenticationMode].ToString();
            HttpResponseMessage response_Cat = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response_Printer = null;
            IEnumerable<Catridge> list_Cat = null;
            IEnumerable<Printer> list_Printer = null;

            if (loginUserId == "1" && authmode == "Admin")
            {
                CustomLogger.Write("Service Call: Get All Catridge: Start");
                response_Cat = await ServiceGet(ClientConfig.ServiceLayerUrl + ClientConfig.GetAllCatridgeUrl);
                CustomLogger.Write("Service Call: Get All Catridge: End");

                var result_Cat = response_Cat.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                list_Cat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Catridge>>(result_Cat).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);                    


                CustomLogger.Write("Service Call: Get All Printer: Start");
                response_Printer = await ServiceGet(ClientConfig.ServiceLayerUrl + ClientConfig.GetAllPrinterUrl);
                CustomLogger.Write("Service Call: Get All Printer: End");

                var result_Printer = response_Printer.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                list_Printer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Printer>>(result_Printer).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);                    

                dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
                mymodel.Catridge = list_Cat;
                mymodel.Printer = list_Printer;
                return View(mymodel);

            }


            else
            {
                CustomLogger.Write("Service Call: GetAllPrinters: Failed|" + response_Printer);
                ModelState.AddModelError(Resources.Resource.MasterError, Resources.Resource.UnableToProcessRequest);
                list_Printer = new List<Printer>();
                return View(list_Printer.AsEnumerable());
            }

        }

    }
```

Now, I have bound the controller result data to WebGrid in MVC:

```
@model dynamic   

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="mainHeading col-md-12"><b>Cartridge List</b></h1>
    </div>  

    <div class="row">
        @{
            WebGrid grid_Cart = new WebGrid(Model.Catridge, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
            @grid_Cart.GetHtml(
         htmlAttributes: new { id = "GridTable_Cart" },
         tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-striped",

        columns: new[] {
grid_Cart.Column("TeamName",header: "Team Name", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
grid_Cart.Column("PartNo",header: "PartNo", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
grid_Cart.Column("PrinterName",header: "Printer Name", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
grid_Cart.Column("LoginUserName",header: "Requester Name", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
grid_Cart.Column("CatridgeColor",header: "Cartridge Color", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
grid_Cart.Column("CatridgeDrumsColor",header: "DrumsColor", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
grid_Cart.Column("Others",header: "Others", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
grid_Cart.Column("AssigneeName",header: "Assignee", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
grid_Cart.Column("Status",header: "Status", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID")
     })
        }

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="mainHeading col-md-12"><b>Printer List</b></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        @{
            WebGrid grid_printer = new WebGrid(Model.Printer, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
            @grid_printer.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "GridTable_Printer" },
    tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-striped",

    columns: new[] {
    grid_printer.Column("TeamName",header: "Team Name", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
    grid_printer.Column("PrinterName",header: "Printer Name", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
    grid_printer.Column("Version",header: "Version", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
    grid_printer.Column("Bundle",header: "Printer Bundle", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
    grid_printer.Column("PrinterFloorNo",header: "FloorNo", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
    grid_printer.Column("PrinterDeskNo",header: "DeskNo", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
    grid_printer.Column("AssigneeName",header: "Assignee", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID"),
    grid_printer.Column("Status",header: "Status", canSort:false,style : "gridTableID")
                })
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

Output for this above code is below:
[image]